# How do I redirect a user to another page based on what the user has entered in the taskbar using Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am looking for a solution for the problem in the Chrome Extension.

If I enter some value in the URL like Mail, Notes, Profile, etc. I want to access the keywords before the values are accessed by the browser and then taken for a search which then changes the URL based on the default search engine.

I want to access the words and then automatically redirect the user to another page. I don't really know if it is possible or not, but thought of asking it to the community.

Or, Is there any way we can make some words which will not be searchable using the Address bar, but it should be that we don't need to make changes in the settings directly, but by using the extension.

Any kind of response are appreciated.

I was trying to capture the value that user enters in the Address bar. I found that we can actually find the link that upon searching from the address bar can be captured using Javascript but could not find if it was possible to capture before the search takes place. (immediately after pressing the enter key or search button).

Comment: "Any kind of response are appreciated." --- [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/omnibox/) The omnibox API allows you to register a keyword with Google Chrome's address bar, which is also known as the omnibox.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, Thanks for your response! Just peeked around the API, and it seems it is not exactly what I am looking for or maybe it is, still figuring it out. But is possible to use the Omnibox API to provide suggestions before the user presses the "Tab" button?? It seems it only starts working upon hitting the tab button.

Comment: I don't know, I've never use the Omnibox. You'll have to read the documentation and experiment. And if the Omnibox doesn't do exactly what you want, you'll have to accept that, as is often the case when programming Chrome extensions.